# Weka API : 'Multiplication is only applicable to doubles!' during buildForecaster

Tags: spring-boot, machine-learning, weka

I'm facing an error when using Weka API in spring boot that says 'Multiplication is only applicable to doubles!' while working with the Weka library. The error occurs during the execution of this code

```
 forecaster.getTSLagMaker().setTimeStampField("date_x");
            forecaster.buildForecaster(wine, System.out);
            forecaster.primeForecaster(wine);
```

the dataset Im using

```
@RELATION dataset

@ATTRIBUTE date_x date "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
@ATTRIBUTE action {scale_up}
@ATTRIBUTE duration NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE useful {0,1}

@DATA
"2023-10-11 10:39:52",scale_up,12,0
"2023-06-26 17:25:35",scale_up,15,1
"2023-03-02 12:53:02",scale_up,3,0
```

the error

```
Multiplication is only applicable to doubles!
    at weka.core.expressionlanguage.common.Operators.times(Operators.java:75)
    at weka.core.expressionlanguage.parser.Parser$CUP$Parser$actions.CUP$Parser$do_action_part00000000(Parser.java:556)
    at weka.core.expressionlanguage.parser.Parser$CUP$Parser$actions.CUP$Parser$do_action(Parser.java:720)
    at weka.core.expressionlanguage.parser.Parser.do_action(Parser.java:224)
    at java_cup.runtime.lr_parser.parse(lr_parser.java:699)
```

even after changing the date to numeric timestamp like this the error still persist

```
@RELATION dataset

@ATTRIBUTE timestamp numeric 
@ATTRIBUTE action {scale_up}
@ATTRIBUTE duration NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE useful {0,1}

@DATA
1688726118,scale_up,12,0
1688726118,scale_up,15,0
```

Why is this error  happening and how to fix it?